# How do I properly swap between <td> and <input> and vice versa, using jQuery in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with data. The data is stored in a database and rather than allowing the user access to phpmyadmin, I am allowing them to alter the data from this table they access from the webpage. I can easily post/insert/update the data, but the difficulty I am encountering involves allowing the user to edit the data in the table.

I want to invoke a swap between a `<td>` and `<input>` and vice versa using jQuery using `.click()`. **jQuery 3.2.1 is used**

**The issue:**

`<td>` are replaced by `<input>` when clicked on. When the `<input>` comes out of focus, the `<input>` swaps back. The first `<input>` of a row can be clicked on more than once. The user can enter anything they want and click outside of the `<input>` and the data can be sent. However, if any other `<td>` in the same row is clicked on, If the first `<td>` of the row is an `<input>` it will no longer swap back into a `<td>`, the `<td>`'s to the right of this if clicked on will now appear as `<input>`'s, but collapse beneath the first `<td>` of the row and remain as `<input>`'s. The `<input>` will not swap back into a `<td>`. The `<input>` stays regardless of clicking outside of it to lose focus so it can revert back into a `<td>`.

I can call whatever text has been entered in the `<td>`, the issue lies within this area of code below, my ID's exist and are called properly, the swap from `<td>` to `<input>` and vice versa is not executing properly.

Thanks in Advance

**The Code:**

```
//### get value of insert button in row when clicking on <td> ###
$("tr").on("click",function(event){

    neededValue1 = $(this).attr('value');
    neededValue = neededValue1;
    console.log("<tr> button Value: "+neededValue);

    //### id clicked in tr w/row value ###
    $('#matName'+neededValue).click(function(){

        // ### Swap <td> with <input>###
        $ele1 = $(this);
        $input1 = $('<input id="UpdatedInput'+neededValue+' "/>').val($ele1.text());
        $ele1.replaceWith($input1);


        //### Save the Input entered and swap back###
        save = function(){
            var $p = $('<td id="matName'+neededValue+'"/>').text($input1.val());
            $input1.replaceWith($p);
        };

        $input1.one('blur', save).focus();
    });


    $('#bed0FL'+neededValue).click(function(){

        $ele2 = $(this);
        $input2 = $('<input id="UD'+neededValue+'"/>').val($ele2.text());
        $ele2.replaceWith($input2);

        save = function(){
            var $p2 = $('<td id="bed0FL'+neededValue+'" />').text($input2.val());
            $input2.replaceWith($p2);
        };

        $input2.one('blur', save).focus();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t3H_DANIMAL/x8an7c0e/

Comment: Please provide HTML or better a JSFiddle

Comment: Don't swap the `<td>` with an `<input>`. Swap the `<td>`'s **contents** with an `<input`>. Otherwise, you'll break your table's layout.

Comment: @rickdenhaan should I place the a <p> within the <td> and call that? or can i just call the .text() of the <td>?

Comment: You can probably just use the `.text()` of the `<td>`, but it would help to see your HTML structure, like Naren Murali mentioned.

Comment: jQuery's .text() is for strings of text. You're looking for .html()

Comment: Make sure you're trying to use the elements as designed. <td> is for a table cell. <input> is for inputting data. They are not interchangeable..

Comment: Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3H_DANIMAL/x8an7c0e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me from your question if there is a specific reason for triggering on the `tr`'s click-event, so I took the liberty to move it to the `td`'s, as well as putting the `td`'s identifying values inside the `data-field` of each `td`, as you can see in the snippets HTML.

In the JavaScript code you can see the `.on("click",...)` triggering a function which sets up a new input field which it fills with the `td`'s text-content and inserts it into the `td`.

I also set the reverse function on the input-fields `.blur()` so that when the text-field looses it's focus, i.e. when you click or tab your way out of it, you remove the input-field and place the text-value from the input inside the `td`.

The `.blur()` is also where I'd put the Ajax-magic to update the DB.

PS! Pardon my CSS hacks, it's a rush job... :)

```js
$('td').on('click', function(event){
  var name = $(this).attr('data-field');
  var value = $(this).text();
  var $input = $('<input>');
  $input.attr({
      'name': name,
      'id':name,
      'type':'text'
    });
    
  $input.val(value);
  
  $input.on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  $input.on('blur',function(){
    $(this).parent().text($(this).val());
    /**
    * INSERT AJAX HERE
    **/
  });
  
  $(this).html($input);
  $input.focus();
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
}

tr {
  height:100%;
}

td {
  padding: 0px;
  word-wrap:none;
  text-wrap:none;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  height:100%;
  width: 25%;
}

td input {
  border:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height:18px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
    <th>col 3</th>
    <th>col 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-field="r1v1">row 1 val 1</td>
    <td data-field="r1v2">row 1 val 2</td>
    <td data-field="r1v3">row 1 val 3</td>
    <td data-field="r1v4">row 1 val 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-field="r2v1">row 2 val 1</td>
    <td data-field="r2v2">row 2 val 2</td>
    <td data-field="r2v3">row 2 val 3</td>
    <td data-field="r2v4">row 2 val 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I trigger the TR event because i am pulling a value dynamically that I need for each row. I needed that value so when I push the update to the DB, it can run properly.

Comment: @Yah_DANIMAL Ok, so the unique value is row-specific, like a database row id? The just set the `data-field`, or other custom attribute, to the id, and use `$(this).parent().attr('data-field')` to access it from the `td` triggered. You can also alter the HTML I provided so that only fields that are to be editable, have an attribute like `data-editable="true"`, and just do `$('tr[data-editable="true"]').on("click",...)` for the trigger instead,

Comment: Yes, like a row id. I'll try this out and get back to you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Yah_DANIMAL You're welcome! Good luck, and let me know if I need to update the snippet for you.

Comment: @Yah_DANIMAL Fantastic! Glad I could help!